# PHP coding style for "no record found", when integer expected

Tags: php, coding-style

What would be the best return value in PHP for a function returning **"no such record found"**?

Consider this shortened example for the question:

```
function getLatestPostId()
{
    $postId = Db::latestPostId();
    return (is_null($postId)) ? null : $postId;
    // Is returning null the best option?
}
```

My usual approach is to return `null`, but I'm mixing `integer` and `null` as possible return types of the function.

Related principles I've read elsewhere:

- Don't return mixed types (e.g. always return a boolean, not a null, if a boolean is expected)
- If returning an array, and no items found, then return an empty array

Comment: You can throw a not found exception. But i think returning null is ok in this case.

Comment: It depends how you view the role of that function. Is an "empty collection" the right return value? Is `false` correct for *"didn't work"*? Maybe an exception if the action is always *supposed to* succeed? There's no one answer.

Comment: If there should always be at least one post, then not founding one must throw an Exception.

Comment: Nitpicker's corner: `return (is_null($postId)) ? null : $postId;` equals `return $postId;` ;-)

Comment: Also, `if value === null return null else value`? Genius! ;-P

Comment: You could also return -1 if real ids are always nonnegative. That way you don't mix types.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Damn, I was trying too hard to find an example where I'm making the decision of whether or not a `$postId` was found :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing fundamentally wrong with returning `null` here if there is no latest post and this is not a problematic state of affairs. Returning mixed types is one of the strengths of languages like PHP and while it can lead to problems if abused, this is IMHO not abuse.

The most important thing is to be consistent: don't mix scalars and arrays as return values, don't mix primitives and object types.

Theoretically, if a latest post is *always* supposed to exist then returning mixed types would be a mechanism of reporting an error condition; in that case things start to get less clear cut and throwing an exception would likely be in order.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what the "expected return type" is when data is found.

1. If you normally return an int (for ids, counts, etc.), bool values (exists) return null for the first case, false for the second case so you can evaluate it using something like `if(!result)`
2. If you normally return an array, return an empty array.

It doesn't really matter what style you use, as long as it *makes sense* and **you stick to it**. If it's consistent throughout your application and it works for you, then it's fine!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your application really. Do you need an ID? In that case throw an exception. Can your application function without an ID? Just return `null` and handle it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, since the invention of `===` ( check value and type ) lots of PHP's own functions return `FALSE` or the intended value, whatever that may be.

If you then get into the habit of using this construct all should be well

```
$x = function();
if ( $x === FALSE ) {
    // error situation
} else {
    // all is well proceed
}
```

Of course a better way would be to use exceptions `throw` `catch`. Then the data type of what is returned in an error situation is standard i.e. an exception object.

```
function getLatestPostId()
{
    $postId = Db::latestPostId();
    if (is_null($postId))  {
        throw new Exception('PostId is not available');
    }
    return $postId;
}

.... 

try {
    $x = getLatestPostId();
    // code when postid is available goes here
}
catch Exception($e) {
    // when posyId is not available do this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not mixing return values is a good principle, but php itself doesn't holds onto that too. It's more like a general programming principle which for other programming languages like C and Java is a strict principle. In Java for instance, a function (or method, like it's called there) can only return one variable type, and a function footprint looks like this to force it (note the `int` in front of the method name, which defines the expected return value):

```
public int getLatestPostId() { // ... }
```

If you want to tell the caller that nothing is found (by giving a warning, or if you want to be stricter, by saying it's an error) you'll have to throw an exception.

Php is a bit different than other programming languages in that it is very flexible with variable types. In example look at this php code:

```
$my_var = 12; // now i'm an integer
$my_var = 12 .' is a number'; // now i'm a string
```

Without doing anything, the variable suddenly became a string. If you would want to do the same in Java, you would have to do something like this:

```
int myInteger = 12;
String myString = myInteger + " is a number";
```

As you can see, you'll have to declare another variable. This is due to Java reserving a certain space in memory for your integer, which has a minimum and maximum size. A String however (which isn't a primitive datatype) can virtually have any size. Php handles all this for you so you don't have to worry about it and never have to tell in advance what kind of value your variable holds.

Now look at some php functions. In example the function `date` returns either a string, or the boolean `false` if something went wrong. `explode` returns either an Array or the boolean `false`. Pretty much every function may return more than one type if anything *can* 'go wrong'.

Now when writing your own functions, you should only keep in mind that whatever you return makes sense. So in your example it would be pretty weird to return the string "no such record found". Also returning the integer `0` makes no sense, as there is no reason whatsoever that an ID cannot be null. Returning `false` or `null` would be both useful return values. Than you can easily check if you got a valid ID by doing:

```
$the_latest_post_id = getLatestPostId();
if(!$the_latest_post_id) {
    // tell the user there was no latest post, or something went wrong while fetching it
}
```

In Java this would not be possible, as the return value should be an integer, and not a boolean, even if something went wrong. The solution; throwing exceptions. Php also allows you to do that. So if you want to be clean and close to your principles, use throw-catch blocks:

```
function getLatestPostId() {
    // try to fetch the post id
    if($no_post_id_found) {
        throw new Exception('No last post id found...');
    }

    // all set, return the id!
    return $last_post_id;
}

try {
    $post_id = getLatestPostId();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Something went wrong: '. $e->getMessage();
}
```

This way an integer is ALWAYS returned, except when the exception is thrown, but then the function would return nothing, not even void.

Summarized: use the flexibility of php, but always be sure it's logical what your function returns. As a rule of the thumb; without any explanation or documentation you should be able to infer what the return value means, AND the return value should be a value you can work with (so never a string when a integer is expected, or an integer when an array is expected, it just makes no sense). And if you are a principal guy, throw exceptions!